# How to get run/result/output history in PyCharm Community

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Community 2019.1 on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Is there any way to keep the run history? Like say I run a script and get the output [first run].

Then I run same script again or another script [second run], I want to be able to refer the output/result of first run.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you just have to right click on the title of the run and click on "pin tab" and it won't close automatically when you start a new run